# How to wrap a block around a div tag?

Tags: html

I want to wrap a block around some text and a table. My problem is that the second identical block moves into the first one with the id 1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id="1">
      <table cellpadding="4"  style="font-size:400%; float:right; width: 250px; border:solid 1px #AAAAAA;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Lorem</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div style="display:table; text-align:justify">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div style="text-align: right;">[Lorem]</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width=100%">
      <table cellpadding="4"  style="font-size:400%; float:right; width: 250px; border:solid 1px #AAAAAA;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Lorem</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div style="display:table; text-align:justify; text-indent:; padding-left:0; padding-right:0;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div style="text-align: right;">[Lorem]</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It looks like this: [image: It looks like this.]

It should look like this:[image: It should look like this.]

What have I add to the div tag with the id "1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
<div style="background-color:#cccccc; overflow: auto;" class="clear_fix">
```

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow: auto;`to div with id `1` like so

```
<div id="1" style="overflow:auto;">
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/Wisdomabioye/yg1wwqxf/embedded/html,result/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```